# Change datetime to different culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a datetime in this format "Wednesday, December 04, 2013". I want to translate it to different cultures at runtime so that i am able to store that in database according to culture.

This is my code:

```
dysMngmt.Day = curntDate.ToString("D");
```

The one line code above is getting the day.
So,please help me.

Comment: Don't store a `DateTime` as `varchar`. Apart form that, a `datetime` has no format, so you have a string instead. Is `curntDate` a string?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)??

Comment: A `DateTime` value doesn't have a format at all. It only gets a format when you convert it into a string. Preferrably you should also store it as a `datetime` value in the database, and only convert it to a string when you want to display it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second argument of the ToString function, which enables you to pick a culture you see fit:

```
curntDate.ToString("D", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

As a side note, why are you saving the date in your database as a string? Why not use a native date date type? It will take less space and allow you comparisons etc., and then you'd just use the currect culture when reading it out of the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply luan.I have a requirement to save in this format.For example if we convert the day "Wednesday, December 04, 2013" to spanish will get "Miércoles, 04 de diciembre 2013".so i want to change it according to language code in database.

Comment: @user2454428 : Yes, but do you really have to do when putting it in the database? Can't you do it when reading from the database instead? Just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very good reason for handling the culture of each date seperatly within the application you should set this at the application level so that the default ToString() works with your intended culture.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162

Also, you should probably also not store dates as text in your database.